# GAN network Disc. loss decreasing and Gen. increasing instead of decreasing

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, generative-adversarial-network

My RNN Gan network which consists of two RNN networks, a generator and a discriminator is ment to generate audio. But it's doing the complete opposit of what it's ment to do, it's really weird. The discriminator loss is decreasing and the generator loss is increasing, so it's doing the complete opposit of what it's ment to do. But it's getting even more weird because the losses are actually dec/inc linear just if they were suppost to do but obviously they're not. So, by what could such a behaviour be caused? Did I swap something out?

Losses: https://pastebin.com/78BmS8iK

**Discriminator/Generator Code:**

```
def build_audio_generator(frame_size):
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512, input_shape=(frame_size, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(512))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(256*frame_size))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.add(Reshape((frame_size, 256)))

model.summary()

noise = Input(shape=(frame_size, 1))

sound = model(noise)

return Model(noise, sound)

def build_audio_discriminator(audio_shape):
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=(2), padding="same", input_shape=audio_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(128))

model.summary()

audio = Input(shape=audio_shape)

# Extract feature representation
features = model(audio)

# Determine validity and label of the audio
validity = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(features)

return Model(audio, validity)
```

**Main(combining both models):**

```
    frame_size = 500
    frame_shift = 128

    num_classes = 1

    audio_shape_disc = (frame_size,256)

    optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)
    losses = ['binary_crossentropy']

    # Build and compile the discriminator
    audio_discriminator = build_audio_discriminator(audio_shape_disc)
    audio_discriminator.compile(loss=losses, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Build the generator
    audio_generator = build_audio_generator(frame_size)

    # The generator takes noise
    noise = Input(shape=(frame_size, 1))

    audio = audio_generator(noise)

    # For the combined model we will only train the generator
    audio_discriminator.trainable = False

    # The discriminator takes generated audio as input and determines validity
    audio_valid = audio_discriminator(audio)

    # The combined model  (stacked generator and discriminator) takes
    # noise as input => generates audio => determines validity
    audio_combined = Model(noise, audio_valid)
    audio_combined.compile(loss=losses, optimizer=optimizer)

    train(audio_generator, audio_discriminator, audio_combined, epochs, frame_size, frame_shift)
```

**Training(train() function shrunk down):**

```
      for s in range(0, Y.shape[1], frame_size):

            audio = Y
            epoch_counter += 1


            if epoch_counter>epochs: break;

            audio_frame = audio[:, s:s+500, :]
            if audio_frame.shape[1]<frame_size: break;

            noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1, frame_size, 1))


            # Generate a half batch of new images
            gen_audio = generator.predict(noise)

            valid = np.ones((1, int(frame_size/2), 1))

            fake = np.zeros((1, int(frame_size/2), 1))


            # Train the discriminator
            d_loss_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(audio_frame, valid)
            d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_audio, fake)
            d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)

            # Train the generator
            g_loss = combined.train_on_batch(noise, valid)

            # Plot the progress
            print(str(epoch_counter) + '/' + str(epochs) + ' > Discriminator loss: ' + str(d_loss[0]) + ' | Generator loss: ' +  str(g_loss))
```

Comment: One thing that would cause such behavior is that the discriminator is too powerful. You could try adding capacity to the generator, reducing the capacity of the discriminator, or updating the discriminator less frequently.

Comment: I solved the problem, I forgave the labels the wrong way around... :D thx